The contraction of Christoffel symbols
I have a question regarding the the contracted Christoffel symbols from David Tongs PDF on general relativity.
He wants to prove that
$$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu v}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_v\sqrt{g}$$
Where $g=\text{det }g_{\mu v}$, is the determinant of the metric.
In one step of the proof he writes
$$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu v}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}\partial_vg_{\mu\rho}=\frac{1}{2}tr(g^{-1}\partial_vg)=\frac{1}{2}tr(\partial_v\text{log }g)$$
I cant really understand what is going on here, could someone explain the two steps in this line?

Wikipedia.

This question is similar to: A helpful proof in contracting the Christoffel symbol?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Do you know the formula for Christoffel symbols near the bottom of this section that follows for a torsion-free connection? If so, you can get the first $=$, while the rest is work with matrices as per @VincentThacker's link.
